# Conditions for solving in NDSolve

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs  but each variable is a probability so I should solve each variable for a range between 0 and 1 and with the sum of all variables equal to 1.

This is the system

```
  Derivative[1][p12][t] == 1 - p11[t] - p12[t] + p22[t], 
  Derivative[1][p21][t] == 2 + p11[t] - p21[t] + p22[t], 
  Derivative[1][p22][t] == 2 + p12[t] - p21[t] - 2 p22[t], 
  p11[0] == 0, p12[0] == 0, p21[0] == 0, p22[0] == 0}, {p11[t], 
  p12[t], p21[t], p22[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

I've tried to put the condition in a function with /; but it doesn't work well. What can I do?

Comment: "the sum of all variables equal to 1" Your initial conditions don't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: If your system of ODEs and initial conditions is set up properly, then probability mass should naturally be conserved (at least within numerical precision).

Comment: Looks like you don't have an equation for `p11` yet. You could add an algebraic equation to your system, such as `p11[t] + p12[t] + p21[t] + p22[t] == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate way to achieve this, is by simply adding the law of total probability as an extra equation. This is possible since your equations are still short by 1:

```
eqs = {Derivative[1][p12][t] == 1 - p11[t] - p12[t] + p22[t], 
  Derivative[1][p21][t] == 2 + p11[t] - p21[t] + p22[t], 
  Derivative[1][p22][t] == 2 + p12[t] - p21[t] - 2 p22[t], 
  Derivative[1][p11][t] + Derivative[1][p12][t] + 
    Derivative[1][p21][t] + Derivative[1][p22][t] == 0, p11[0] == 1, 
  p12[0] == 0, p21[0] == 0, p22[0] == 0}
```

Solve:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, {p11[t], p12[t], p21[t], p22[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

It seems, however, that your system yields negative probabilities even though they sum up to 1. You probably need to rethink the equations to make sure that this can't happen:

```
sol /. t -> 1
```

> {-2.5504, 1.74916, 0.878252, 0.922986}